# How to to scan deceives using Bluetooth in ionic and transfer data?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm creating an Ionic app,which scan devices using Bluetooth and transfer data to the selected deives. How Can I do this in ionic platform,is there is any plugin/Package for it.

Comment: https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

Comment: I tried this.I'm able to list paired devices.But how can I transfer data to another device and display

Comment: Have you tried this one https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#write

Comment: I tried this.But not working in my mobile phone